# the feeling you get sometimes in someone's wedding

Tags: word-request

I think I've heard it somewhere but fail to remember. When you're single and you're attending someone's wedding, it may come to you that you want to get married, too. The thought or feeling might go away the day after. Is there a word or expression to describe this? As a context, think of two friends attending a wedding going,

> A: You know what, Sam? I want this. I wanna get married. Yea, it's time to settle down.
>
> B: Easy pal. You know it's just ...... . Many people get that.

Take the liberty of rearranging the words if there's an idiom or fixed expression to describe this.

Comment: Settle down, not settle in. You settle in after you move to a new dwelling. You settle down when you get married and start a family.

Comment: There's a phrase used mainly of women, **wedding fever**.

Comment: @TRomano thank you. I just edited that part. wedding fever is a nice phrase though it's used mainly for women.

Comment: *sentimental* might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general phrase that comes to mind is

> caught up in the moment

which means one feels all the good, or bad, feelings of an event.

> Easy pal. You know you're just *caught up in the moment*. Many people get that.

On a larger scale it can be called

> group think

where a large group begins to all think the same way.

Possibly a more specific phrase for your situation is

> [wedding envy](http://magazine.foxnews.com/love/got-wedding-envy-when-talk-your-partner-about-marriage)

it occurs when all your friends are getting married and you're not.

Since life stages happen in waves, I once asked an older friend of mine

> Me: Nick what does it mean when all your friends are getting married?
>   Nick: Do you mean for the first time?

Or maybe you are thinking about

> [couple envy](http://www.singlematters.com/is-couple-envy-getting-you-down/)

when you are jealous of people in a committed relationship.

Comment: is there a phrase with wedding in it? something like wedding flink/spaz/whim or something? im saying this because i think there was a phrase with wedding in it, but im not sure so im going wild guesses here.

Comment: I know what you're saying, it's like when some women are around a baby they get all **broody**

Comment: broody :) that was a hell of a word. exactly, wishing to get married. so there's possibly no word for that. +1 thanks for the brilliant phrases and words.